# Sampling the data in InfluxDB on the query level

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a really big dataset for which I'd like to fetch a diagnostic sample. Till now I've been fetching all the data and sampling on my own machine, but currently it causes both influxdb and my app to run out of memory.

Is there a way to maintain the entire dataset on the DB level and downsample in a query?

Let's say that I'm interested in 1% of the entire measurement data. How would that query look like?

e.g. I want to get 1% of all values of a measurement.

**Example case:**

*Measurement X*

```
time val1 val2
---- ---- ----
  0  A1   0.5
  1  A2   0.7
  2  A1   1.0
  3  A3   1.5
  4  A4   0.7
  5  A3   0.5
  6  A7   1.0
  7  A1   0.5
  8  A10  0.7
  9  A2   0.1
```

Magic Query - 10%

```
time val1 val2
---- ---- ----
  5  A3   0.5
```

Magic Query - 20%

```
time val1 val2
---- ---- ----
  9  A2   0.1
  4  A4   0.7
```

Comment: Maybe `SAMPLE() with a GROUP BY time() clause` is what you're looking for (see [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#sample). Also you can consider using continuous queiries if you'd like to store sampled data for re-use. Alternative is to use capacitor scripts, but that's a tough way.

Comment: @YuriLachin One problem I'm getting with `SAMPLE()` is that it's sampling values and not rows/entries. I need to have a samples of the entire rows/entries.

Comment: Do you really need sampling? Why not aggregation? e.g. `SELECT MEAN(val1), MEAN(val2) FROM measurement WHERE <time condition> GROUP BY time(1h)` -> it will return val1, val2 hourly averages for the selected time period. Of course you can return also MIN/MAX, deviations, etc.

Comment: @JanGaraj Unfortunately I cannot just use aggregation. The algorithms I need to run on the data (e.g. creating bins for a histogram) require original values.

Comment: Do you have nice linear timestamp sequence (so in theory `ELAPSE("field") % <CONSTANT> = 0` can be used for "time sampling")?